# how to check if the inputted variable is existing as a primary key in my MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to check if the variable i inputted on my android application (which is loaded into an android device) is existing on my MySQL database

this is my codes

tav_enterstudentno.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_enterstudentno"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
    android:text="Enter Student No" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_enterstudentno"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn_enterstudentno;
TextView throwhere;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tav_enterstudentno);
    tavinputswindow();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void tavinputswindow()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.tav_enterstudentno);

btn_enterstudentno = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn_enterstudentno);
btn_enterstudentno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        enterstudentno(); //POPS UP DIALOGBOX ASKING FOR STUDENT NO.
    }
});
}

//POPS UP DIALOGBOX ASKING FOR STUDENT NO.
    public void enterstudentno()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Enter Student No."); //alert.setMessage("Message");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this); // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() //FOR OK BUTTON
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
            {
                String studentno = input.getText().toString();
                //CHECK DATA BASE FOR EXISTENCE OF STUDENT ID NO *****



            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()//FOR CANCEL BUTTON
        {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
          {
             dialog.cancel(); // Canceled.
          }
        });
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

here's what i want to happen; when btn_enterstudentno was pressed an alert message will pop up asking the user to enter the student no. if the OK button was pressed in that pop up alert message and provided that the user already typed something in the alert message text field, the program will check if the entered student number is a primary key on a table in a certain MySQl database.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: android cannot talk to mysql directly. you need a web service (e.g. a php script) to take some http get/post parameters from android, then return the results in some format (e.g. json).

Comment: yes but can you help me do the php file? i already have the jsonparser class from this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ thanks